# How send url for recovery profile with devise_token_auth gem like devise url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

In my application installed gem Devise and devise_token_auth.

When I request the recovery link then I got this url to my email: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=&reset_password_token=oYGgW9-ht774ztwiigVy`

but I want this url `http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=8sfhjjfzErYpgUim-UYt`

What I must change in my source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit_password_path(:user)` translate to `edit_user_password_path`

Here path needs to be interchangeable with url.

Hope it worked.

Comment: edit_password_path(:user)    => edit_user_password_path

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers     Check this link